# Parsing String in java with Special Char

Tags: java, string, parsing, tokenize

i'm trying to tokenize a string in such a way that ...

Example String

```
Public Static void main(String[args])
```

String tokenizer tokenize like

```
public
static
void
main
String
args
```

but i want to tokenize in such way

```
public

static

void

main
(
String
[
args
]
)
```

means its also print the char on which string  moves to tokenized

Comment: Please edit your post, I think you want something else which is not clear here.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with `StringTokenizer`, use regex instead.

Comment: I got it, give me a sec and I'll post an answer up

Comment: Do you want to create Lexical Analise  ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String[] tokenise(String str){
    String progress = "";
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(int c = 0; c < str.length(); c++){
            char ch = str.charAt(c);
            // Skip next char if the current char is an escape character
            if(ch == '\\'){
                c++;
                continue;
            }
            // If current char is to be tokenised, add progress and char to list
            if(ch == ' ' || ch == '(' || ch == ')' || ch == '[' || ch == ']'){
                    if(!progress.equals("")) list.add(progress);
                    list.add(ch+"");
                    progress = "";
            }else{ 
                progress += ch;
            }
    }
    String[] result = new String[list.size()];
    for(int c = 0; c < result.length; c++) result[c] = list.get(c);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Works, but only for this example, what if there were \ or / ?

Comment: Thanks, I added support for escape characters.

Comment: Much better, I posted a solution that handles everything that isn't a letter, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SOQ17
{

   public Scanner scan;

   public String test;

   public boolean check = true;

   public SOQ17()
   {

      System.out.print("Enter your string.\n");

      scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      test = scan.nextLine();

      for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++)
      {

         if((test.charAt(i) >= 'A' && test.charAt(i) <= 'Z') || (test.charAt(i) >= 'a' && test.charAt(i) <= 'z'))
         {

            System.out.print(test.charAt(i) + "");
            check = true;

         }

         else
         {

            if(check)
            {

               System.out.println("");

            }

            System.out.println(test.charAt(i));
            check = false;

         }

      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      while(true)
      {

         SOQ17 soq = new SOQ17();

      }

   }

}
```

Here is how mine works, it will create a new line for every thing that is not a letter. If it is a letter, however, it will simply print it out. Also, I used boolean 'check' to ensure that the proper formatting is applied when alternating back and forth between letter and not.

Comment: No? What confuses you about it?

Comment: I re-read it and understand now, however it would be more use to return an array or list with each element.

Comment: ....oh, well in that case, i'll get back to work. This is why I asked for thoughts! :)